# Pythonでの複数の辞書の値の比較について

Tags: python

値の左から順に同じグループになります。例えば、group1では、group１のaの1が一つのグループで、また別に、group１のaの2のグループ、group１のbの1のグループ、group１のaの1のグループとなり、4つのグループが存在することになります。

```
dict1 = {"group1":["a","a","b","a"],"group2":["a","a","a","a","a"]}
dict2 = {"group1":["1","2","1","1"],"group2":["1","1","2","3","4"]}
```

以下がdict1,dict2という辞書に対して行いたい処理です。

1. それぞれのgroupの中で値を照合
2. 違う種類がどれくらいあるか判別（group１の中では、aの1は2つあり、aの2は1つ、bの1は1つなので、3種類存在する。
3. 辞書として抽出する

以下のような辞書がほしいです。

```
result = {"group1":3,"group2":4}
```

知識不足ながらプログラム案を考えてみましたが、当然ながら、dict2の値でしか分類できていません。ご教示お願い致します。

```
dict3 = {}
import collections
for k in dict2.keys():
  c = collections.Counter(dict2[k])
  if len(c) >= 2:
    dict3[k] = len(c)

print(dict3)

#出力
{"group1":2,"group2":4}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
dict1 = {"group1":["a","a","b","a"],"group2":["a","a","a","a","a"]}
dict2 = {"group1":["1","2","1","1"],"group2":["1","1","2","3","4"]}

result = {k: len(set(zip(dict1[k], dict2[k]))) for k in dict1.keys()}
print(result)

# {'group1': 3, 'group2': 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

`dict1`と`dict2`のリストの各値を`('a','1')`のように`tuple`でまとめたものを要素とする集合(set)をつくります。
その集合の要素数が求めたい個数になるかと思います。

```
dict1 = {"group1":["a","a","b","a"],"group2":["a","a","a","a","a"]}
dict2 = {"group1":["1","2","1","1"],"group2":["1","1","2","3","4"]}

ret = {}
for key,lst1 in dict1.items():
    lst2 = dict2[key]
    s = set([(v1,v2) for v1, v2 in zip(lst1, lst2)])
    print(s) # {('b', '1'), ('a', '1'), ('a', '2')} など
    ret[key] = len(s)

print(ret) # {'group1': 3, 'group2': 4}
```